# Security Issues with Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, anaconda

There has been some back and forth between myself and the IT department of a company I recently began working regarding the installation of Python / Anaconda suite on my work PC.  The IT department is making claims of security risks (with Anaconda) but I suspect it’s more of a matter of them not wanting to give me access.  My suspicion is based, not on my IT knowledge, but due to the fact that I’ve used Anaconda at my last job with no issues.  I’m hoping for some insight of enterprise risks (if any) associated with installation of Anaconda.  To summarize the situation/my knowledge:

•   I am not a developer, nor do I come from an IT/enterprise risk background. I’ve used Python for analytics, data cleansing and report automation

•   Current and past companies are within the finance industry, i.e. confidential information lives on the network

•   I’m requesting Anaconda as opposed Anaconda Enterprise

•   I’m requesting Python version 3.6.4

I’m not trying to write-off IT’s concerns.  What I’m trying to do is better understand the situation, educate myself and either alleviate their concerns or propose an alternative all parties can work with.
So my questions are:

1. Are their security threats associated with leveraging Anaconda?  If so, what specifically?
2. If the risk is too great, what are alternatives to simply installing the Anaconda Suite?

Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Developers are notorious for their sloppy security practices. Even worse is when they drive security requirements. I would not have a development workstation on a production network. Dev worksations belong in their own network segregated with Layer 2 switches to enforce the boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Are their security threats associated with leveraging Anaconda? If so, what specifically?

It depends on the environment. Do you have admin privileges ? How the global GPO policy looks like ? For example if you don't have an admin rights you can't do things like create a socket, access network stack on os level and vice versa. The thing is, that you can do similar damage with CMD/PowerShell also. Is the former secure than the latter, I don't think so ....

> 2. If the risk is too great, what are alternatives to simply installing the Anaconda Suite?

It depends on what kind of functionality you need from Anaconda, maybe you can use different python interpreter/framework, but from security perspective looks the same.

Usually "IT Stuff" don't have a clue how to implement OS/Domain/Security in a proper manner so their solution is to tell everybody that it's a security risk. In these days, everything is a security risk.

Comment: 1. I do not have admin privileges.  Not sure how all GPO settings are configured, but I know I do have some privileges that if used maliciously or stupidly could cause problems.  For example, I can execute code in DOS and PowerShell but I have limited install permissions.  2. That answer doesn't surprise me, as the question was pretty open-ended.  My take away is the 'risk' isn't Anaconda its self, it's the power given to me by its installation.  Possible workarounds are plentiful and depend on how much maintenance / back-and-forth we are willing to put up with.

Answer (score 0):

One could argue that *any* programming environment is a *potential* security risk.

But such an argument is rather unconvincing in any office environment where you will probably find a well-known office suite installed that comes with its own built-in programming environment! You can cause plenty of mayhem with VBA macros hidden in Word en Excel documents... Especially when these documents are sent to unsuspecting co-workers.

To put it more bluntly, *any* environment that is not nailed down to the point of being unusable is a potential security risk. Can you e.g. run programs off a USB drive? Or open Office files from them? Or even copy files to them?

You could ask IT what their specific objections are?

BTW; You don't need administrator privileges to install Anaconda for yourself. Only if you want to install it for all users on your machine.

---

**Edit**: Another approach is to bring your own laptop and use Python on that.

This is an approach I'm using. And I would suggest using a laptop loaded with a UNIX-like operating system like a Linux distribution or one of the BSD variants. All of these come with a lot of tools out of the box and since they have decent package management (as opposed to ms-windows) basically every open-source tool you can think of is easily available. There is a learning curve associated with this, but on these systems tools are meant to work together instead of existing as pre-packaged one-trick ponies.

For example, I keep yearly logbooks of work-related stuff that should be documented. These logbooks can run into 200-300 pages, with hundreds of illustrations and graphs. For such a thing, ms-word just doesn't cut it; I've tried several times. So I use LaTeX, python, gnuplot and a host of other tools for it. And the whole thing is kept under revision control as a matter of course.

This laptop isn't connected to the network at work, so it cannot be a threat to that.

Comment: Any time the them 'open source' come up in research or discussion they freak out (never-mind the fact that filezilla, winzip, R and Power BI are open source).  Basically, they have an 'open-source' policy that is leveraged when it's convenient.  Vague comments about unsupported packages came up, although when asked, no specific packages  that would pose a threat were named.

Comment: @lewisj In that case, it's time to think out of the box. See edited answer. You might want to get your manager on-board before you do something like that.

Comment: @ Roland Smith Good recommendation, I do bring my personal laptop for some tasks but the issue is I need to be able to connect to the network.

Comment: @lewisj Having an unmanaged (i.e. untrusted) laptop on their network will probably give the admins hives. :-) I'm guessing that to begin with the MAC address of your regular PC is on a list of authorized MACs, so that machines not on that list can only access a guest network, or are not connected altogether. That would be a first line of defense, but there might very well be others, depending on how paranoid the admins are. In any case, get you boss onboard, and let him take the fight to IT department if necessary.